# Latex showing "undefined control sequence" error when using cases inside align*

Tags: amsmath, align, cases

I am trying to use LaTeX to run the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
    A\left(x\right)&=
        \begin{cases}
            1, &\text{if } x \eq 1\\
            0, &\text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
```

I want it to show the multiple values A(x) can have, however I am getting two errors at the same line and saying the same thing.

```
 undefined control sequence <argument> ...begin {cases} 1, &\text {if } x \eq
1\\ 0, &\text {otherwise} ...
l.54 \end{align*}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Could anybody please tell me how do I make LaTeX display what I would like?

Comment: Maybe I'm daft, but what is `\eq`?  Perhaps `=`?

Comment: wow. I thought since <, >, <= and => were special characters, which were written like in bash for example, = made no exception. That was indeed the solution, to a one-symbol typo which produced two errors. thanks

Comment: Or `\neq`. lol.

Comment: also it you get a better semantics by using `\text{if $x=1$}` instead of just writing the textual comment in `\text`

Comment: For a single unnumbered displayed equation, it's better to use `equation*` rather than `align*`.

Comment: As an old FORTRAN user (in both senses of the word), I could immediately relate to the problem of slipping into `\eq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) for the next time.

The following code should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scaled]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    A\left(x\right)=
    \begin{cases} 1, &\textrm{if } x = 1 \\
        0, &\textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\textrm{}`?

Comment: Are the first five `\usepackage` statements necessary?